# How to make combination of two field values unique?

Tags: form, field

I make use of the front-end entry form for an event registration process. The event is the main entry, and every event registration an entry of a related registration section. The challenge is to see whether a user has already been registered for an event. Today, I do that with a database query before the entry form loads. But for some reason, this works not always (for example when users reload the page). How could I make the combination of two fields ("user id" and "registration status") unique? (Normally, I would do that on a database level with a unique index over the two fields.)

Comment: You could get entries for the specific section by their `authorId` and if they have one don't load the form else load the form and let them register.

Comment: That is exactly what I do today. But nevertheless, I get duplicated entries from time to time.

Comment: If there is only one entry from a user in a specific section you should only see one entry come back when you query based on the `authorId`, what does your template look like?

Comment: No, there is more than one entry from a user in a section.

Comment: I will now add a text field containing string composed of event_id and user_id and make this field value unique using the following plugin: https://github.com/joshangell/craft-unique-value

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you have two sections:

- events
- registrations

Is the user logged in? If yes, you can save the user id in your registration entry. In your events template you can check now, if a registration entry exists that is related to this event and the current user. 
See example code (untested).

```
{% if currentUser %}

   {% set query = "userIdField:"~ currentUser.id %}
   {% set results = craft.entries({
      relatedTo: entry.id,
      section:'registrations'
      search: query
   }) %}

{% endif %}

{% if results|length %}
    user is already registered
{% else %}
    show registration form
{% endif%}
```

If your user is not logged in, you could (temporarily) store the registration information in a cookie (check out this plugin: https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies) and do a similar check.

Comment: Yes, the user logged in and your proposal is more or less what I do already. The problem is that I still get duplicated entries from time to time.

Comment: Perhaps the user press the registration button twice, or he use the back button. In certain circumstances this could create a second entry. To avoid the "double click" you could disable the button with javascript. Have you activated the CSRF Protection -> https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection? Hope this helps.

Comment: No, CSRF protection has not been enabled yet. I will try that. Thank you very much.